# Clone a collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongo-collection

I want to clone a MongoDB collection and save it on the same server with a different name. So for example right now I have the following collections: demo1.categories, demo1.users and demo2.users.

I want to have a "demo2.categories" which is identical to "demo1.categories". (It just has a different name.)

Comment: The accepted answer was arguably the best method back in 2012, but now db.cloneCollection() is a good & better method to get a solution.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yet again the [MongoDB documentation comes to the rescue](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Developer+FAQ#DeveloperFAQ-HowdoIcopyallobjectsfromonedatabasecollectiontoanother?)

assuming that the collection actually is named "demo1.categories":

```
db.demo1.categories.find().forEach( function(x){db.demo2.categories.insert(x)} );
```

Comment: As of 2.1+ you can do db.demo1.copyTo("demo2");

Comment: `copyTo` blocks all other operations in mongod instance

Comment: in 2.0.4 this way converted all my collection's int values into double values... So, this method will not guarantee 100% equality...

Comment: Issue with copyTo is that it requires the "anyAction" role on "anyResource" , which isn't recommended to be given to all users. (and might not be granted to you if you're in a large organization) Apparently, `cloneCollection` is a better option since all it needs are read\write permissions. Of course, the above answer also works.

Comment: These things not worked for me. It says Message.find(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: Actually I want it to do automatically with the help of cron job on nodejs. So whenever cron job hits the command, then simply copy the collection and paste to the new collection

Answer (score 31):

The most simple & efficient way is by using [copyTo()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/), so you can use:

```
db.source.copyTo("target");
```

& if `"target"` doesn't exist, it will be created

**-- Update --**

According to [CopyTo Documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.copyTo/#behavior), Because `copyTo()` uses eval internally, the copy operations will block all other operations on the mongod instance. So it shouldn't be used on production environment.

**-- Update --**

Because `CopyTo()` uses [`eval()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/eval/#dbcmd.eval) internally & `eval()` is deprecated since version 3.0, so `CopyTo()` is also deprecated since version 3.0.

Comment: Don't run copyTo on a production system. As mentioned in a comment for the accepted answer it will block other operations on your mongod instance effectively making it unavailable for the duration.

Comment: @JamesWahlin thanks for the note, I updated the answer, so everyone can see it easily

Comment: The `cloneCollectionAsCapped` also blocks other operations. I discovered it empirically...

Comment: Deprecated since version 3.0.

Answer (score 30):

This is the fastest way to clone your collection:

```
mongoexport -d db_name -c src_collection | mongoimport -d db_name -c dst_collection --drop
```

it will clone **src_collection** in **db_name** to **dst_collection**. Or you can do it in two steps on bson level:

```
mongodump -d db_name -c src_collection
mongorestore --drop -d db_name -c dst_collection ./dump/db_name/src_collection.bson
```

Comment: This way isn't just easiest, but also guarantees you 100% identity on binary level, but find() and insert() way doesn't. For example, it converts all your integer records into numerics, etc

Comment: for authentication, and to connect to remote server, add following args to both sides of the pipe-  `--host="whatever" --port="27017" --username="myuser" --password="mypass" --authenticationDatabase="admin"`

Answer (score 23):

The fastest option is

```
db.myoriginal.aggregate([ { $out: "mycopy" } ])
```

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/caolan/async in my node.js application and this didn't work for the mongodb node.js driver - I'm now using the `find().forEach(....)` solution - still upvoted this because it works in the console

Comment: Yeah, this is the fastest way for copying from one collection into another db.myoriginal_collection.aggregate([{$match: { id: "id" }},{ $out: "myoriginal_duplicate_collection" } ])

Answer (score 2):

there already has a command for this.

Copy a single collection from one server to another.
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/cloneCollection+Command

Comment: You are correct that this command will allow you to copy from one server to another.  However, the original question refers to the same server.  As the documentation indicates, you will lose your collection if you attempt to use the cloneCollection command for the original question's goal

Answer (score 2):

If you're concerned about speed then I found that by using `aggregate` with `$project` and `$out` to be a 100 times faster, not sure if there are restrictions though, but you would have to create a set of fields that you'd want to copy
For example:

```
// Set of fields in the categories collection
var setOfFields = {field1:1, field2:1.......}
db.demo1.categories.aggregate([{ "$project": setOfFields},{ $out: "demo2.categories"}]);
```

This copies (projects) the selected set of fields for all documents from `demo1.categories` to `demo2.categories`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `db.cloneCollection()` method, it is depreciated from the current version `4.2` instead try to use `mongoexport`.

[depreciated collection method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/#db.cloneCollection)

Answer (score -4):

In the mongo console, you can do the following as well, where db_host is the machine where db_host has the db with the collection that you want to clone.

```
use <db>
db.cloneCollection(<collection>, <db_host>)
```

Comment: Sorry there was some formatting issues, it should be use db_name then db.cloneCollection(collection_name, db_host)

Comment: and reverse db_host and collection name i.e. db.cloneCollection(host, collection)

Comment: that doesn't work: { "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "can't cloneCollection from self" }

Comment: check mongo docu: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/

The collection in the MongoDB instance that you want to copy. db.cloneCollection() will only copy the collection with this name ** from database of the same name as the current database ** the remote MongoDB instance. If you want to copy a collection from a different database name you must use the cloneCollection directly.