# How to clone a collection from remote Mongo server to local Mongo server?

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have read few posts on StackOverflow regarding the `cloneCollection` database command. It indeed works just fine from the shell.

But is there a way to run the `cloneColection` using the C# Mongo Client?

I've tried:

`local_database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ cloneCollection : \"<collection>\", from: \"<server>:27017\" }"`

I do get an `Ok` response, but nothing happens...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Duplicate a mongodb collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19494066/duplicate-a-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 0):

After digging around here is the right syntax to run the administrative command using the C# client...

```
var command = new BsonDocumentCommand<BsonDocument>(new BsonDocument(new List<BsonElement>()
{
    new BsonElement("cloneCollection", "<database_name>.<collection_name>"),
    new BsonElement("from", "<server_ip>:27017"),
    new BsonElement("query", "{}")
}
));
local_database.RunCommand<BsonDocument>(command);
```