# How to execute the mongo cloneCollection command to copy a collection to a remote server

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to copy a collection from one database to an instance on another server.  From [other stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933307/clone-a-collection-in-mongodb) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933307/clone-a-collection-in-mongodb), I understand the correct way to do that is with this command:

```
{ cloneCollection: "<collection>", from: "<hostname>", query: { <query> } }
```

via http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/cloneCollection/

However, I don't understand where do I enter this command?  It isn't accepted as...

```
$ mongod { cloneCollection: "remote", from: "ec2-whatever-amazon.com"}
```

How do I copy a remote collection at `db.remote.collname` to `db.local.collname` using this cloneCollection syntax via command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MongoDB database commands are run using `db.runCommand()` from the mongo shell. Refer to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/.

Try something like this (using another database command for simplicity):

```
$ mongo
 > db.runCommand({ isMaster: 1})
 {
    "ismaster" : true,
    "maxBsonObjectSize" : 16777216,
    "localTime" : ISODate("2014-02-18T22:30:04.417Z"),
    "ok" : 1
 }
 >
```

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing... ```$ mongo --eval '{ cloneCollection: "<collection>", from: "<hostname>", query: { <query> } }'```  Thanks!