# Copy collection in MongoDB (2.4) without Eval

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using a hosted MongoDB (2.4) service through MongoLab. They don't allow *eval* command and I need to copy a collection to a history collection nightly. We're using the official C# driver and I have to do this from within my C# code (I can't run *mongodump* or execute a shell). The options I've found are

1. eval with '*copyTo*', but that's not allowed
2. server-side *find().forEach*, but I can't find a way to do this query in the C# MongoDriver (*CommandDocument*, *CommandWrapper*, I can't figure out the syntax if it's even possible).
3. client-side full copy

I'd prefer to not to do the client-side copy. Any suggestions?

Comment: foreach query: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933307/clone-a-collection-in-mongodb

Comment: I need to stay in the same database so I can't use cloneCollection since it doesn't take a target collection name. FYI