# Migrate data between different Database and same collection?

Tags: mongodb

Migrate data between different Database and same collection?

I need migrate all data the db-show1,collections table-some, and table-some2 in db-show2 table-some, table-some-two.

```
show dbs
db-show1
db-show2

use db-show1
show collections
table-some
table-some-two

use db-show2
show collections
table-some
table-some-two
```

some idea?

thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clone a collection in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933307/clone-a-collection-in-mongodb)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11554762/how-can-i-copy-collection-to-another-database-in-mongodb and also refer this http://blog.shlomoid.com/2011/08/how-to-move-mongodb-collection-between.html and this as well http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.cloneCollection/