# Updating documents from a MongoDB collection to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I'm trying to backup some data that i stored on a collection to another collection hosted on a single db.
I came up with a very simple solution, which works but very slowly, so i was trying to find a faster way to do this. Here is what i tried:

```
def updater():
    COL1= DB1.WData.find({})
    for x in COL1:
        Values = {"$set": {"datetime": x['datetime'], "amount": x['amount']}}
        Query = {"datetime": x['datetime'], "price": x['price']}
        DB2['COL2'].update_one(Query, Values, upsert=True)
```

As i said, this works but very slowly; and since i have around 23k records i was trying to find a way to speed it up. Any advice is appreciated

Comment: How often do you want to take backup?

Comment: Once every 12 hours i think

Comment: What is the purpose? Only backup and recovery incase of failure? Or copy to another table?

Comment: Both of them; right now it's a backup, but i'm planning to use that db later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you are looking for two different things.

1. You can use `mongo dump` and `mongo restore` to backup and restore. [Refer this documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/backup-and-restore-tools/#back-up-a-database-with-mongodump)

You should not be taking backup to another collection. Because when something goes wrong with the sever, backup helps you to restore the data. When the server crashes, you can restore the data with the dump which is taken using `mongodump`. `mongorestore` helps to restore the dump.

2. If you just want to copy all the docs to another collection, you can use `copyTo` or  `$out` or `mongoexport` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8933307/clone-a-collection-in-mongodb)

You can cron it as you want to do this every 12 hours once.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `aggregation`, check the $merge pipeline stage. Documentation:
[$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html)